# 404: That's an error in Google AMP Cache

Tags: amp-html, google-amp

I cannot understand why I got 404: That's an error even `Powered by AMP ⚡ HTML – Version 1456440290687`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello, AMPs</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mmdroid.biz/myjobs/index.html" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "NewsArticle",
        "headline": "Open-source framework for publishing content",
        "datePublished": "2015-10-07T12:02:41Z",
        "image": [
          "imgs/logo.jpg"
        ]
      }
    </script>
    <style amp-custom>
      /* any custom style goes here */
      body {
        background-color: white;
      }
      amp-img {
        background-color: gray;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
```

Above is part of my coding.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The AMP cache only contains valid AMP pages. Your page is not valid AMP due to lots of online styles so it's not in the cache so trying to access via the cache gives a 404. Visit below site with console open to run in development mode and show the errors you need to fix:

Visit: http://www.mmdroid.biz/myjobs/index.html#development=1

You also need valid NewsArticle structured date (including an image):

https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mmdroid.biz%2Fmyjobs%2Findex.html

Comment: Valid NewsArticle structured data is not required (this is only required for AMPs appearing in the Top News Carousel).